# Monaco Editor, how to overwrite an extra lib?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

For a project of mine i have integrated Monaco editor instance.
But when using:

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(content,filename);

I cannot overwrite the existing type.
In my case i have a type called "item" which refers to the current item that is being selected.
If a user closes the interface monaco.editor.dispose() will be called.
And after the user opens it again the addExtraLib function will run again.

Is there a way to make all extra libs dissapear?

I already tried to call:
javascriptDefaults.setExtraLibs([]);
And also the dispose function before running the addExtraLib.
Somehow the extraLibs dont get removed (version monaco-editor@0.31.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade the version. I had the same issue with the referenced version. I downgraded to "monaco-editor": "^0.26.1"